# SQL recursive query that gets all ancestors of an item

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID       parent_id   name
---------------------
1        2            first 
2        4            second
3        3            third
4        5            fourth
5        -           fifth
```

Ancestors  list of  `first` should be  `(2, 4, 5)`

Comment: Can you show your effort so far? from your data I can't see how "first" has an associated parent of 2,4 and 5

Comment: Can't you just do a join?

Comment: In sql server you can do it with a CTE, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916597/sql-server-recursive-query for the basic algorithm

Comment: I think you mean _ancestors_, not _parents_.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
with name_tree as (
   select id, parent_id, name
   from the_unknown_table
   where id = 1 -- this is the starting point you want in your recursion
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, c.name
   from the_unknown_table c
     join name_tree p on p.parent_id = c.id  -- this is the recursion
) 
select *
from name_tree
where id <> 1; -- exclude the starting point from the overall result
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87d0c/1

Comment: Very slick.  I was actually looking for a recursive function to put in stored procedure to do this very thing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Well played, sir.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all - returns only the first row. What am I missing?

Comment: @Andrey: you are right. The join for the recursive part was the wrong way round. See the update (and the SQLFiddle). Interesting that nobody noticed this in over two years...

Comment: And just swap p and c if you need to get the children: c.parent_id = p.id

Comment: Needs "with recursive name_tree" to work in modern Postgres

Comment: @BeRecursive: you are correct `recursive` is indeed required by the SQL standard (and Postgres) - however Microsoft chose to ignore the standard when they implemented that feature in SQL Server and `recursive` will result in an error there - and the question is about SQL Server

Comment: SQLFiddle for Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87d0c/13/0

Comment: You can also get all the descendants by changing `p.parent_id = c.id` to `p.id = c.parent_id`. Magic :)

Answer (score 16):

You can use something like this:

```
with parents as 
(
  select ID, parent_ID
  from t
  where parent_ID is not null
  union all 
  select p.ID, t.parent_ID
  from parents p
    inner join t on p.parent_ID = t.ID
      and t.parent_ID is not null
      and t.ID <> t.parent_ID
)
select *
  , parents = '(' + stuff
    (
      (
        select ', ' + cast(p.parent_ID as varchar(100))
        from parents p 
        where t.ID = p.ID
        for xml path('')
      ), 1, 2, ''
    ) + ')'
from t
order by ID
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03d5f/11).

This combines two very common T-SQL techniques - using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get a hierarchy and using FOR XML PATH to get a CSV list.

Comment: Good answer + explanation, nice!