# How to call a recursive function in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-function

I have a table as follows

```
cat_id  Cat_Name    Main_Cat_Id

1       veg         null
2       main course 1
3       starter     1
4       Indian      2
5       mexican     2
6       tahi        3
7       chinese     3
8       nonveg      null
9       main course 8
10      indian      9
11      starter     8
12      tahi        11
13      chinese     11
```

(**Main_Cat_Id** is **cat_id** of previously added category in which it belongs)

This table is used for the categories the product where **veg** category has the two sub category **main course** and **starter** which is identify by **main_cat_id**
and those subcategories again has sub category as **indian** and **mexican**

And this categorization is dependent on the user; he can add more sub categories to indian, mexican also so that he can have any level of categorization

now I have to select all the subcategories of any node like if I take veg i have to select

```
(1)veg > (2)main course(1) > (4)indian(2)
                           > (5)mexican(2)
       > (3)starter(1)     > (6)thai(3)
                           > (7)chinese(3)
```

to form the string as 1,2,4,5,3,6,7

to do this i wrote a sql function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSubCategory_TEST]
( @MainCategory int, @Category varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Cat_Id FROM Category WHERE Main_Cat_Id=@MainCategory)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TEMP TABLE
        (
            CAT_ID INT
        )
        INSERT INTO @TEMP(CAT_ID) SELECT Cat_Id FROM Category WHERE Main_Cat_Id=@MainCategory
        DECLARE @TEMP_CAT_ID INT
        DECLARE CUR_CAT_ID CURSOR FOR SELECT CAT_ID FROM @TEMP
            OPEN CUR_CAT_ID
            WHILE 1 =1
                BEGIN
                FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_CAT_ID
                INTO  @TEMP_CAT_ID;
                IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
                    SET @Category=@Category+','+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @TEMP_CAT_ID)
                    SET @Category = [dbo].[GetSubCategory](@TEMP_CAT_ID,@Category)
                END
                CLOSE CUR_CAT_ID
                DEALLOCATE CUR_CAT_ID
    END
    return @Category
END
```

but this function keep on executing and not gives the desired output i don't understands what wrong is going on plz help me to get this

Comment: `while 1=1` ?? it'll go infinite! ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL recursive query that gets all ancestors of an item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749095/sql-recursive-query-that-gets-all-ancestors-of-an-item)

Answer (score 15):

You dont need a recursive function to build this, you can use a Recursive [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for that.

Something like

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
    cat_id INT,
    Cat_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Main_Cat_Id INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 1,'veg',null
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 2,'main course',1
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 3,'starter',1
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 4,'Indian',2
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 5,'mexican',2
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 6,'tahi',3
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 7,'chinese',3
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 8,'nonveg',null
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 9,'main course',8
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 10,'indian',9
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 11,'starter',8
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 12,'tahi',11
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 13,'chinese',11

;WITH Recursives AS (
        SELECT  *,
                CAST(cat_id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '\' ID_Path
        FROM    @TABLE
        WHERE   Main_Cat_Id IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.*,
        r.ID_Path + CAST(t.cat_id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '\'
        FROM    @TABLE t INNER JOIN
                Recursives r    ON  t.Main_Cat_Id = r.cat_id
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Recursives
```

Comment: The categories are not fixed. These categories and the level of categories are not fixed.

Comment: @Rhushikesh: Read the answer! You are confusing the *sample data* construction needed to match your example with the subsequent solution to the posed problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am ashamed, but I used @astander  scipt to give string result.

First I created data  you gave.
Second I collect rows which I need
And then using `XML` I put everything in one row (function `STUFF` removes first comma)

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
    cat_id INT,
    Cat_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Main_Cat_Id INT
)

DECLARE @Collected TABLE(
    cat_id INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 1,'veg',null
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 2,'main course',1
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 3,'starter',1
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 4,'Indian',2
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 5,'mexican',2
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 6,'tahi',3
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 7,'chinese',3
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 8,'nonveg',null
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 9,'main course',8
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 10,'indian',9
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 11,'starter',8
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 12,'tahi',11
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 13,'chinese',11
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 14,'chinese',6

DECLARE @nodeID INT = 1;
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX);

;WITH Recursives AS (
        SELECT cat_id, main_cat_id
        FROM @TABLE
        WHERE Cat_Id = @nodeID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT T.cat_id, T.main_cat_id
        FROM @TABLE AS T 
        INNER JOIN Recursives AS R 
            ON  t.Main_Cat_Id = r.cat_id
)
INSERT INTO @Collected
SELECT cat_id
FROM Recursives


SELECT @result = STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + CAST( cat_id AS VARCHAR)
        FROM @Collected
        ORDER BY cat_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1,1,'')

SELECT @result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor is looping infinitely because you asked it to keep going until 1 no longer equals 1:

> `WHILE 1 =1`

`1=1` is always true so the loop never ends, and you don't explicitly `break` out of it anywhere.

You would do well to study some examples of cursors, for example [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180169.aspx) in the Microsoft T-SQL documentation. They are quite formulaic and the main syntax rarely needs to vary much.

The standard approach after `open`ing the cursor is to do an initial `fetch next` to get the first result, then open a `while` loop conditional on `@@FETCH_STATUS = 0` (0 meaning [successful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187308.aspx)).

Because you're looking only for *unsuccessful* cursor fetch states inside your cursor:

> `IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0`

The setting of `@Category` will only happen once the cursor has gone past the last row in the set. I suspect this is exactly what you don't want.

I'm also not sure about the scoping of the `@Category` variable, since it's an input parameter to the function; I generally create new variables inside a function to work with, but off the top of my head I'm not sure this will actually create a problem or not.

More generally, although I don't totally understand what you're trying to achieve here, a recursive function involving a cursor is probably not the right way to do it, as [Adriaan Stander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23910518/1837122) suggests.