# Create a tree structure from a structured table in sql database

Tags: sql, database, data-structures

I have a table that tracks movement of data, it looks like:

| From_Id | To_Id |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| NULL | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 10 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 5 | 9 |
| 9 | NULL |
| 10 | NULL |

I want to structure and store every possible paths (e.g 1,2,8,9) and im unsure about the best possible way to do this with SQL.

I started off with a simple while loop, but got a problem at id=4 where it gets 2 new paths. I tried finding a solution which uses a tree structure, but I couldnt find anything that fits my case.

What is a good solution here?

Edit:
Im using microsoft sql server
desired output:

| From_Id | To_Id | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 1 | 1, |
| 1 | 2 | 1,2, |
| NULL | 3 | 3, |
| 3 | 4 | 3,4, |
| 4 | 5 | 3,4,5, |
| 4 | 6 | 3,4,6, |
| 5 | 7 | 3,4,5,7, |
| 6 | 10 | 3,4,6,10, |
| 2 | 8 | 1,2,8, |
| 8 | 9 | 1,2,8,9, |
| 5 | 9 | 3,4,5,9, |
| 9 | NULL | NULL |
| 10 | NULL | NULL |

I tried this from [How to call a recursive function in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910245/how-to-call-a-recursive-function-in-sql-server)

```
DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE(
    From_Id INT,
    To_id INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT NULL,1
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 1,2
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT NULL,3
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 3,4
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 4,5
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 4,6
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 5,7
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 6,10
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 2,8
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 8,9
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 5,9
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 9,NULL
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 SELECT 10,NULL

;WITH Recursives AS (
        SELECT  *,
                CAST(To_id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' ID_Path
        FROM    @TABLE2
        WHERE   From_Id IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.*,
        r.ID_Path + CAST(t.To_id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ','
        FROM    @TABLE2 t INNER JOIN
                Recursives r ON t.From_Id = r.To_id
)

SELECT  *
FROM Recursives
```

Which gave me an extra row (it gets much larger when i have  10k + rows)

| From_Id | To_Id | ID_Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 1 | 1, |
| 1 | 2 | 1,2, |
| NULL | 3 | 3, |
| 3 | 4 | 3,4, |
| 4 | 5 | 3,4,5, |
| 4 | 6 | 3,4,6, |
| 5 | 7 | 3,4,5,7, |
| 6 | 10 | 3,4,6,10 |
| 2 | 8 | 1,2,8, |
| 8 | 9 | 1,2,8,9, |
| 5 | 9 | 3,4,5,9, |
| 9 | NULL | NULL |
| 9 | NULL | NULL |
| 10 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: What is your database engine? What is the expected output? Is it a result set? What will be columns of that result set?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, Im updating the orginial post with the necessary information

Comment: see connect by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server