# SQL parent child recursive query - Includes Relatives relatives

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, parent-child

I have the following Table with two columns.

```
Parent  Child
A       C
A       D
B       A
B       E
C       H
J       C
F       G
G       I
```

So I need to pass in a Parent of A and I am supposed to get the following back- All of a's Parent's and children but Also all of the Parents and Children to those associated to A (either parent or children) I need all their parents and children and so on.

SO in the example of A being passed to the proc I would get the following

```
A   C
A   D
B   A
B   E
C   H
J   C
```

If F was Passed I would just get

```
F   G
G   I
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL recursive function that gets all ancestors of an item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749095/sql-recursive-function-that-gets-all-ancestors-of-an-item)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from test 
where parent in (
    select parent from test
    where parent = 'F' or child = 'F'

    union 
    select child from test
    where child = 'F' or parent = 'F')

or child in (
    select parent from test
    where parent = 'F' or child = 'F'

    union 
    select child from test
    where child = 'F' or parent = 'F');
```

Comment: I don't think this will handle deep recursion.

Comment: Thanks Johnny, why is it that you think that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is similar to the link given in the comments but accounts for both parent and child recursion. Hopefully it will work for you.

```
WITH relationships AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM Table
   WHERE Child = 'A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.*
   FROM Table p
   JOIN relationships pa on pa.Child = p.Parent
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.*
   FROM Table c
   JOIN relationships ch on ch.Parent = c.Child
) 
select *
from name_tree;
```

Comment: With the example of F and G it only brings back F as G and not G & I

Comment: What about Adding the Line under Where Child = ' A' add OR Parent = 'A' This seems to work

Comment: But that still wont show G& I- i need it to be recursive.