# Parent Child SQL Recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, parent-child

I have seen similar but not Exactly the same requests.

If I had the following table

```
Parent  Child
1       2
1       3
4       3
5       1
6       1
5       7
8       9
```

I selected "1"  I would expect back all records where one is the parent or child but also all related parents and children for instance row "5 , 7" because 5 is the parent of "1"

so the result set for 1 would be

```
Parent  Child
1       2
1       3
4       3
5       1
6       1
5       7
```

So it would ***NOT*** include the row

```
Parent  Child
8       9
```

This is as close as I can get so far

```
;WITH LinksDown AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM RecursiveTable
   WHERE Parent = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT rt.*
   FROM RecursiveTable rt
   JOIN LinksDown ld on ld.Child = rt.Parent
),

LinksUp AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM RecursiveTable
   WHERE Child = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT rt.*
   FROM RecursiveTable rt
   JOIN LinksUp lu on lu.Child = rt.Parent
) 

select distinct *
from LinksDown

Union All 
select distinct * from LinksUp
```

But this has the following output which is far from whats needed

```
Parent  Child
1       2
1       3
1       2
1       3
5       1
6       1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL parent child recursive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538873/sql-parent-child-recursive-query)

Comment: What are you struggling with / What have you tried?

Comment: I updated question with my latest SQL....

Comment: I would try it using a temp table, keep inserting related ids (both parents and children) to the temp until no more new ids inserted.

Comment: Do you have an example Tim?

Comment: Why did you include 4--3 in output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two approaches. The first uses a CTE that is quite inefficient. The problem is that during recursion you cannot examine all of the other rows in the result set. While you can build a list of the rows that have contributed to a given row, you cannot check to see if you already reached that row via another path. The second approach uses a loop to populate a table with relations one step at a time. It is a much better method than the CTE.

Left as an exercise for the reader: Will the two methods terminate in the presence of a cycle in the "tree", e.g. 1 > 2 > 3 > 1?

```
-- Sample data.
declare @RecursiveTable as Table ( Parent Int, Child Int );
insert into @RecursiveTable ( Parent, Child ) values
  ( 1, 2 ), ( 1, 3 ),
  ( 4, 3 ),
  ( 5, 1 ),
  ( 6, 1 ),
  ( 5, 7 ),
  ( 8, 9 );
select * from @RecursiveTable;

-- Walk the tree with a recursive CTE.
--   NB: This is woefully inefficient since we cannot promptly detect
--   rows that have already been processed.
declare @Start as Int = 1;
with Pairs as (
  select Parent, Child, Cast( Parent as VarChar(10) ) + '/' + Cast( Child as VarChar(10) ) as Pair
    from @RecursiveTable ),
 Relations as (
  select Parent, Child, Cast( '|' + Pair + '|' as VarChar(1024) ) as Path
    from Pairs
    where Parent = @Start or Child = @Start
  union all
  select P.Parent, P.Child, Cast( R.Path + P.Pair + '|' as VarChar(1024) )
    from Relations as R inner join
      Pairs as P on P.Child = R.Parent or P.Parent = R.Child or
        P.Child = R.Child or P.Parent = R.Parent
    where CharIndex( '|' + P.Pair + '|', R.Path ) = 0
  )
  -- To see how terrible this is, try: select * from Relations
  select distinct Parent, Child
    from Relations
    order by Parent, Child;

-- Try again a loop to add relations to a working table.
declare @Relations as Table ( Parent Int, Child Int );
insert into @Relations
  select Parent, Child
    from @RecursiveTable
    where Parent = @Start or Child = @Start;
while @@RowCount > 0
  insert into @Relations
    select RT.Parent, RT.Child
      from @Relations as R inner join
        @RecursiveTable as RT on RT.Child = R.Child or RT.Parent = R.Parent or
          RT.Child = R.Parent or RT.Parent = R.Child
    except
    select Parent, Child
      from @Relations;
select Parent, Child
  from @Relations
  order by Parent, Child;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could still do this with a CTE, as part of a stored procedure.  (The performance will be lousy, but this should work.)

The normal method of using recursive CTE's commonly generates 3 columns:  ParentID, ChildID, RecursionLevel.

My suggestions is to return one more column...  A string that is the concatenation of all of the parents IDs.  (Probably with some separator value, like a vertical pipe.)  From there, you should be able to select every row where the `IDString` column contains your ID.  (In your case, it would be "1".)  This should return every record where your search ID occurs somewhere within the hierarchy, and not just as a parent or child.

**EDIT:**  Here is a sample.  I'm using curly brackets { and } as my separators,  I also realized that the code would be cleaner if I added an "IsLeaf" indicator to reduce duplication, since the leaf-level records would contain the IDs of all of their ancestors...

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(P int, C int)  -- Parent & Child

INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 1, 2 );
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 1, 3 );
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 3, 4 );
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 3, 5 );
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 2, 6 );
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 5, 7 );
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 6, 8 );
INSERT @MyTable VALUES( 8, 9 );

-- In order to user a recursive CTE, you need to "know" which records are the 'root' records...
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ( null, 1 );

/*
        9
       /
      8
     /
    6
   / 
  2   
 /     
1   4    Using this example, if the user searched for 1, everything would show up.
 \ /       Searching for 3 would return 1, 3, 4, 5, 7
  3        Searching for 7 would return 1, 3, 5, 7
   \
    5
     \
      7
*/


WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    SELECT C as ID, 
         0 as Level, 
         CONVERT(varchar(max), '{' + CONVERT(char(1), C) + '}') as IDList,
         CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @MyTable B Where B.P = 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as IsLeaf
    FROM @MyTable A
    Where A.P IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT child.C as ID, 
          Level + 1 as Level, 
          IDList + '{' + CONVERT(varchar(max), child.C) + '}' as IDList, 
          CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @MyTable C Where C.P = child.C) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as IsLeaf
    FROM RecursiveCTE as parent
    INNER JOIN @MyTable child ON child.P = parent.ID
)
SELECT IDList -- Every ID listed here is a row that you want.
FROM   RecursiveCTE 
WHERE  IsLeaf = 1
AND    IDList LIKE '%{3}%'
```

Comment: Could you send an example?

Answer (score 1):

It's not efficient but it will do the job:

```
select * from pc;
declare @t table (cid int);
declare @r int;
insert into @t (cid)values(1); -- this is the "parent"
set @r=@@rowcount;
while @r>0 begin
    insert into @t 
    (cid) select pid from pc where (pid in (select cid from @t) or cid in (select cid from @t) ) and pid not in (select cid from @t)
    union select cid from pc where (pid in (select cid from @t) or cid in (select cid from @t) ) and pid not in (select cid from @t);
    set @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
end;

select * from pc where pid in (select cid from @t) or cid in (select cid from @t);
```

The table will be

```
1   2
1   3
4   3
5   1
6   1
5   7
8   9
```

The output will be :

```
1   2
1   3
5   1
6   1
5   7
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this, for my Tree Structure data Source:

```
;WITH items AS (
  SELECT Cg_Code, Cg_Name
  , 0 AS Level
  , CAST(Cg_Name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
  FROM GroupsCustomer WHERE Cg_Relation =0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.Cg_Code, i.Cg_Name
  , Level + 1
  , CAST(Path + '/' + CAST(i.Cg_Name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
  FROM GroupsCustomer i
  INNER JOIN items itms ON itms.Cg_Code = i.Cg_Relation
  )

SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY Path
```