# SQL query to get latest updated data with "Updated From" column

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I'm dealing with old database that contain a table with this kind of schema.

```
+----+------+--------------+
| id | name | updated_from |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | A    | NULL         |
| 2  | B    | NULL         |
| 3  | AA   | 1            |
| 4  | BB   | 2            |
| 5  | AAA  | 3            |
+----+------+--------------+
```

What I try to do is to get the latest update with specific `id`, for example, if I want to know latest update from `A` with `id=1` or `AA` which of course is `AAA`. Sadly, the schema doesn't have any `timestamp` column.

To make it easier, this is my expected result when I search for `id=3`.

```
+----+------+--------------+
| id | name | updated_from |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | A    | NULL         |
| 3  | AA   | 1            |
| 5  | AAA  | 3            |
+----+------+--------------+
```

I apologize for any unclear explanation and thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**
To make it clearer, I hope this can help :

`1:A:NULL -> 3:AA:1 -> 5:AAA:3`

Which every update any row, the previous row copy the id and put it to `updated_from` column into the new row, this make them like chained.

Given that example, if I search for any arbitrary id, I will get the previous also the next chain id.

After reading @hofan41 comments, I've to come to this answer [Generating Depth based tree from Hierarchical Data in MySQL (no CTEs)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291159/4692649).

which lead to my modified version of @f00 answer.
Schema and example data exactly same with first table I presented.

```
drop procedure if exists `table1_hier`;

delimiter #

create procedure table1_hier (
    in updated_from_id smallint unsigned
)

begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_depth smallint unsigned default 0;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
create temporary table hier (
    updated_from smallint unsigned,
    name_id smallint unsigned,
    depth smallint unsigned default 0
) engine = memory;

insert into hier
    select updated_from, id, v_depth
    from table1
    where id = updated_from_id;

create temporary table tmp engine = memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do
    if exists(select 1
              from table1 p inner join hier on p.updated_from = hier.name_id
              and hier.depth = v_depth) then

        insert into hier
            select p.updated_from, p.id, v_depth + 1 from table1 p
            inner join tmp on p.updated_from = tmp.name_id and tmp.depth = v_depth;

        set v_depth = v_depth + 1;

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;
    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;
end while;

select
    p.id,
    p.name,
    b.id as updated_from,
    b.name as name_from,
    hier.depth
from
    hier
    inner join table1 p on hier.name_id = p.id
    left outer join table1 b on hier.updated_from = b.id
order by
    hier.depth, hier.name_id;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end #
```

But if I searching with `id=3` I only got the next chain id not the previous.

```
+----+------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| id | name | updated_from | name_from | depth |
+----+------+--------------+-----------+-------+
| 3  | AA   | 1            | A         | 0     |
| 5  | AAA  | 3            | AA        | 1     |
+----+------+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: Based on the tables you show, the only result you'll get when you want ID=3 is the middle result in the smaller table because ID is acting as a primary key. I don't understand how you can make AA = AAA unless both those values are in the same row somewhere that you are not showing?

Comment: What you are asking is a way to traverse a linked list encoded inside an sql table. There is no easy way to traverse a linked list without issuing multiple queries (1 for each node you visit).

Comment: Looks like this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916597/sql-server-recursive-query should help you get what you need.

Comment: How It should work? Why Id 3 returning this result set? Why not AA?

Comment: @Mike what I mean that `A`, `AA`, `AAA` is chained changes and in one group with their respective id, such that, if searching with their id, for example `3`. I will got any rows that chained with `id=3`. I got the partial solution of it based on @hofan41 comments, I'll edit my question.